# Why this line fails to compile only on MSVC but not on Clang or GCC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

I have an CI on GitHub Action which runs Windows Server 2022 with Visual Studio 2022.

Also, I have in the same Action a matrix to run Clang (macOS) and GCC (Linux).

On GCC and Clang it compiles fine. On MSVC I get this error:

```
D:\a\carimbo\carimbo\src\soundfx.cpp(11,29): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::' [D:\a\carimbo\carimbo\build\carimbo.vcxproj]
D:\a\carimbo\carimbo\src\soundfx.cpp(11,24): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected [D:\a\carimbo\carimbo\build\carimbo.vcxproj]
D:\a\carimbo\carimbo\src\soundfx.cpp(11,29): error C2059: syntax error: ')' [D:\a\carimbo\carimbo\build\carimbo.vcxproj]
D:\a\carimbo\carimbo\src\soundfx.cpp(12,37): error C3536: 'to_copy': cannot be used before it is initialized
```

The code:

```
#include <algorithm>

...

const auto to_copy = std::min(static_cast<size_t>(length), buffer.size()); // This line
```

What I am doing wrong? If I change to `const auto to_copy = 0;`, it compile fine.

The project is configured to use C++17 and I use `auto` and other stuffs in the project without any problems.

If you want to see: https://github.com/carimbolabs/carimbo/actions/runs/6833798890/job/18585920088